# Why is the p-value for a proportion difference hypothesis test not equal to the probability of obtaining that result or more extreme (for a coin)?

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

According to Goodman (2008) "A p-value means only one thing (although it can be phrased in a few different ways), it is: The probability of getting the results you did (or more extreme results) given that the null hypothesis is true."

So let's use an example of a coin. We take p1 = 0.5 and make n1=1000000 (a very large number) and take p2=1 n2=4. And perform the following hypothesis test:

H0: p1-p2=0

H1: p1-p2!=0

We get Z=-2 and a p-value of 0.0455.

But, according to Goodman, the p-value be equal to P(x>=4) which, using binomial distribution gives P(x>=4)=(4!/(4!*(4-4)!))*0.5^4*0.5^0. Which gives 0.0625 (or 0.5^4).

So my question is why is the p-value 0.0455 and not 0.0625?

Thank you in advance!

Goodman SN, Royall R (1988). Evidence and scientific research. American Journal of Public Health 78(12):1568–1574

Comment: My guess is you're using a Z-test and so a normal approximation for the first P-value, then an exact binomial probability for the second.  Generally, speaking, normal approximations get you at only about two places of accuracy. (Also it's not exactly clear what test statistic you're you using for the second P-value.)

Comment: @BruceET that makes sense, I was not thinking about the fact that in the first case it is an approximation, thank you!